# Azure Portal Hotkeys

Tags: azure, azureportal

Azure Portal used to have these really helpful shortcuts, recently I've discovered some of those do not work. Any one got any idea if they changed completely or removed or? If they changed, where's the updated list?

```
Hub Menu – when you are focused on the left hand ‘hub’ in the portal:
H – shows the portal start board (as customised by you!) # doesnt work
N – shows the notification hub and any recent notifications # works as "C" now
A – shows the active journey hub – this is a starting point for any sets of blades you have opened (a VM’s configuration, etc) # doesnt work
/ – show the search hub # works as earlier
B – shows the billing hub (all your subscriptions and credit left) # opens some navigation sidebar
C – shows the Create/New Hub blade # works as earlier

Blade Navigation – If you have several blades open (e.g. VMs, a VM, a VM’s setting) you can navigate between the individual blades (i.e. between the blades in an active journey)
J – move the input focus to the prior blade # doesnt work
K – move the input focus to the next blade # doesnt work
F – move the input focus to first blade # doesnt work
L- move the input focus to the last blade # doesnt work
```

Tested on preview and current portal with latest Edge and Opera

Comment: You can see the latest keyboard shortcuts in the portal itself (Help + Support icon on top right corner --> Keyboard shortcuts) or press `?`.

Comment: BTW, I submitted a PR for this here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/pull/626.

Comment: I wonder why they removed the `home` one, it was the most usefull...

Comment: The home shortcut wasn't removed. It's G+D (for "go to dashboard"). Note that you have to hold down G while you press D, it's not G then D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as pointed out:

```
Support icon on top right corner --> Keyboard shortcuts or press "?"
```